# Windows 10: Limit Start Menu search Folders while indexing other folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, start-menu, windows-search

I have a weird situation I am in. I have this one folder which has a large number of subfolders and files inside of it that I need to be able to search through reasonably quickly. Because of this, I have added it as an indexed folder which makes searching super quick.

However, now all these indexed files can be searched with ease in the start menu which is becoming a problem as it is resulting in incorrect searches. A lot of the files in this huge tree have names similar to other applications or files that I am specifically trying to search for in the start menu.

Therefore, my question. Is it possible to index a folder in windows explorer while also preventing those indexed files/subfolders from appearing in windows search? I have tried googling a solution however everything I seem to find is either "how to exclude folders from windows search" or "how to index folders" but not both.

It is worth mentioning that adding the folder in the "Excluded Folders" setting in "Searching Windows" in the settings app does not prevent the files in the indexed folder from appearing in Windows Search.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to index a folder in windows explorer while also
> preventing those indexed files/subfolders from appearing in windows
> search?

No. You can pick folders to index in Control Panel, Indexing Options, Modify, and then add or delete folders you wish to index.

But three things:

1. Folders you choose to index will be included in Search.
2. When you have made changes to locations, you should re-index (Advanced Options in the Indexing window) and allow indexing to run overnight.
3. Anything (indexed or not) can be found in File Explorer, top right Search bar.